# swift and core graphics , catch the points and undo images

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, core-graphics, swift4

I'm try to make a special drawing app in swift4 and core graphics but I have three questions or problems in code below :

```
import UIKit

class ViewTest : UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView!

    var secondStart : CGPoint? // the second start point
    var startTouch : CGPoint? // start point
    var secondTouch : CGPoint?
    var finalTouch : CGPoint?
    var currnt : CGContext?
    var secondImage : UIImage?
    var images : [UIImage] = [] // image array so i can undo
    var arrayOfPoints : [CGPoint] = [] // array of points so i can choese one of them to start touch

    @IBAction func undoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if images.count > 0{
            images.removeLast()
        }

        if arrayOfPoints.count > 0 {
            if arrayOfPoints.count == 2 {
            arrayOfPoints.removeAll()
            }else{
            arrayOfPoints.removeLast()
            }
        }

    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first
        secondStart = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
        if startTouch == nil || images.count == 0{
        startTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
            arrayOfPoints.append(startTouch!)
        }else{
            for point in arrayOfPoints{
                if secondStart == point{
                    startTouch = point
                    // the point is to small , the user can't catch the point
                }else{
                    //don't stroke the path
                }
            }

        }


    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        secondTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)

        if currnt == nil {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingPlace.frame.size)
            currnt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        }else{
            currnt?.clear( drawingPlace.bounds)
        }

        images.last?.draw(in: drawingPlace.bounds)

        currnt?.beginPath()
        currnt?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        currnt?.setLineWidth(3)
        currnt?.setLineCap(.round)
        currnt?.move(to: startTouch!)
        currnt?.addLine(to: secondTouch!)
        currnt?.strokePath()

        let img = currnt?.makeImage()
        drawingPlace.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: img!)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        finalTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)

        arrayOfPoints.append(finalTouch!)
        print(arrayOfPoints.count)

        currnt = nil
        secondImage = drawingPlace.image
        images.append(secondImage!)

    }

}
```

**First One** : when I press the undoButton the last line doesn't not disappear until I draw another line , I tried to put setNeedsDisplay() func
but it didn't solve it .

```
@IBAction func undoButton(_ sender: Any) {
            if images.count > 0{
                images.removeLast()
            }

            if arrayOfPoints.count > 0 {
                if arrayOfPoints.count == 2 {
                arrayOfPoints.removeAll()
                }else{
                arrayOfPoints.removeLast()
                }
            }  
        }
```

**Second One** : i have array of points that collect the first touch and the final touch , if the start touch not empty the start touch equals some of that points , the problem is : i want if the second start equal , close , near the point then the start touch equal point .

```
for point in arrayOfPoints{
                    if secondStart == point{
                        startTouch = point
                        // the point is to small , the user can't catch the point
                    }
```

**Third One** : if the second start not near of any point so I don't want to draw anything .

```
for point in arrayOfPoints{
                    if secondStart == point{
                        startTouch = point
                        // the point is to small , the user can't catch the point
                    }else{
                        //don't stroke the path
                    }
```

any idea I would be thankful , thanks for your time .
 mazen.

Comment: Hi there - I think you might want to look at one of the many online tutorials on this topic. From a design perspective the approach you’ve chosen is going to give you a lot of headaches. Take a look, for example, at this one: https://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit . Hope that helps.

Comment: I wish I can @sparky but all my project about straight lines and I can't figure out another way to draw I straight lines

Answer (score 0):

**First One Solved** : I don't know if this is the right way but it's Easier way , after remove last image , just put the images in the drawing place

```
    @IBAction func undoButton(_ sender: Any) {
                if images.count > 0{
                    images.removeLast()
                } 
                for image in images{
                    drawingPlace = image
                }else{
                secondStart = images.fisrt
                drawingPlace.image = secondStart
                }

    }
```